# Load large table from MySQL via AWS Glue

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, aws-glue

We have an AWS Glue job to copy a large MySQL table ( ~4billion records ) to an S3 bucket.

We have many other smaller tables and all the tables load without any issues but this 1 table with 4 billion records is running for hours and failing with communication links failure.

We have tried all the options for partitioning using hashexpression, hashpartition and used boundedexecution options to improve the performance. We have also increased the number of workers in Glue to 10 and job timeout to 24 hours, but still no good.

Also we have indexes created on the columns we are trying to partition and bookmark in the Glue job, and we are still getting job failures.

This is the Python code we use to load the data:

```
import sys

from awsglue.utils import getResolvedOptions
from awsglue.context import GlueContext
from awsglue.job import Job
from pyspark.context import SparkContext

args = getResolvedOptions(sys.argv, ["JOB_NAME","S3_BUCKET_NAME"])

sc = SparkContext()
sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")

glueContext = GlueContext(sc)
spark = glueContext.spark_session

job = Job(glueContext)
job.init(args["JOB_NAME"], args)
bucket_name = args["S3_BUCKET_NAME"]


s3_path = "s3://" + bucket_name + "/flow_datad0036103"
datasource0 = glueContext.create_dynamic_frame.from_catalog(
    database="centerstagedb",
    table_name="repo_flow_datad0036103",
    additional_options={"jobBookmarkKeys":["Data103_PK","FLOW_FK"],"jobBookmarkKeysSortOrder":"asc","hashexpression":"FLOW_FK","hashpartitions":"1000"},
    transformation_ctx="datasource0",
)

datasink4 = glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(
    frame=datasource0,
    connection_type="s3",
    # connection_options={"path": s3_path},
    connection_options = {"path":  s3_path, "partitionKeys": ["FLOW_FK"]},
    format="parquet",
    transformation_ctx="datasink4",
)
job.commit()
```

Has anyone else encountered issues loading large tables from MySQL via AWS Glue?

Many thanks

Comment: Increase the timeout.

Comment: thank you we have already tried this, do you have any other suggestions?

Comment: @BogdanGheoca I'm running on a similar issue. I'm wondering fi you solve it?
One idea that I had was to create small chunks of queries to fetch data by specific ids, and then join the all the small chunks df in a big dataframe.